# Custom list view

Tags: android

I have one edit text named package_name i want that when i click on edittext an activity should open with listview having all package names. And i want that when click on a cell a window should popup which will show details of package and a button when click on button the control should transfer to listview. I want to add checkbox on each cell when i click on checkbox that package_name should be selected and will show in edittext of package_name at the beginning. I want something like this. Is this possible to create? Or anyone can tell some other options also for this scenario.

Comment: yes it is possible ..tel me what have you tried??]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible....Try with this simple tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/